# Swift - Localize big array of strings

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I have a multiple arrays with each over 300 strings. Is there any way I can easy localize these without doing every single string? I have each array in two different languages, and this is an example:

```
var freeQuestions = ["En",
                         "To",
                         "Tre",
                         "Fire",
                         "Fem",


var freeQuestionsEnglish = ["One",
                         "Two",
                         "Three",
                         "Four",
                         "Five",
```

Comment: What do you want exactly? A `Localizable.strings` file? How to read the values from it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
var arrStr = ""
freeQuestions.forEach {
    arrStr += " , NSLocalizedString(\"\($0)\",\"\")"
}
print(arrStr)
```

then copy paste what you see in the log and replace the array in code with it , so on with other arrays

Comment: The problem with this is that you can't use `genstrings` on the code to generate the original localized strings file.